# What's the cheapest way to store a large amount of data into a smart contract?

Tags: solidity, mapping, games, merkleization

I'm working on a smart contract in which we need to store some addresses along with their pending rewards periodically,

so the most first approach is to have a mapping of addresses to an int, like below:

```
mapping(address => uint256) pendingRewards;
```

**The problem is that when you want to set/update all these data at once, it will cost a lot of gas to loop through the mapping and update them all.**

so in other words, let's say I have a table of addresses and pending rewards,
consider it's a huge huge table,
what would be the best practice to set/update these data into a smart contract?

!! MerkleTree would not solve the problem because we can't retrieve `pendingReward` with the `address` as the key from that.

Comment: By the way, the Merkle Trees is the most common solution, you store the huge mapping offchain - Db, Excel, Json, etc, and users will claim rewards by providing their reward amount from offchain storage.

Comment: thank you @tenbits this is actually what I was thinking about. 
also we can keep the totalClaimed in the contract, which will solve my issue.
so merkleTree + offchain data is the solution!

Answer (score 2):

> The problem is that when you want to set/update all these data at once, it will cost a lot of gas to loop through the mapping and update them all.

You need to design your smart contract logic in a way that there is no need to do this kind of batch update operations.

This is quite well understood problem. There are multiple well-known decentralised projects like Uniswap, Sushi, Balancer which you can study to understand how it is done.

Comment: could you please provide more detail on where exactly should I look for?

Comment: Start with Sushiswap v2 source code and their reward pools.

Comment: i'm not looking for a reward pool or staking logic, you didn't get my question. but thank you anyways.